# Flowable CMMN planitem reenter?

Tags: flowable

guys.
I'm studying flowable CMMN. I have a quetions need to help. when I complete planitem's task, the planitem instance come to 'completed' state. if my data change to fit the entry condition of this planitem, how can I get a new instance of this planitem? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to be able to reenter an already completed plan item. The plan item needs to be marked as repeatable. Otherwise it can only be executed once.